# Using isProd and isDev in scala twirl templates in Play Framework 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice, twirl

I'm migrating an Play 2.4 application to 2.5 and now `play.Play.application().isProd` is deprecated. I use this in various places in scala.html templates. (To decide weather or not to use minimized javascript.)

It seems unreasonable to pass this in as parameters into every template.

Is there a way to inject the `Application` into the template directly?

Comment: Play 2.6 will introduce template constructors. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates#Template-constructor

Answer (score -1):

I used the same method in 2.4, in 2.5 I switched to `play.Environment.simple().isProd`

Comment: -I'm pretty sure you should be using `play.Environment.underlying().isProd` according to the javadoc in `Environment`, `simple()` is always in test mode.- Disregard that, underlying is not a static method. But still, I don't think simple is the correct choice here.

Comment: You're right, I just tested and simple() always returns test mode. I love that those guys just deprecate everything but don't tell what to use instead...

Comment: They do tell you to use an injected Application or Environment in the deprecation comment. However as far as I can tell injection is not possible in the templates.

Comment: I started a thread about this on the google groups, but I still didn't get a solution: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/play-framework/wu1SFlndtRQ